# PDF Map Export with Zoom-in Effect from ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, pdf, zoom

I would like to create a pdf map (export map) from ArcMap data, with the possibility of zooming in on the exported PDF.

Answer (score 1):

To do this is a function of your PDF reader after exporting your map as PDF.

Below I am using Adobe Acrobat Reader:

1. right-click in the grey area near the existing tools
2. choose the Marquee Zoom tool to add that to the tools available to you
3. Click on the Marquee Zoom to drag out a rectangle and zoom in.

It works just like a Page Zoom In from ArcMap.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your feedback but to be honest I did not get what you really mean. could you please explain it more. what exactly I should do in Adobe Reader?

Comment: I have now numbered the steps, but really I think it will be obvious when you try it.